# Handling OnClick event for canvas in javascript and getting its coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling, onclick, coordinates

I have a canvas for drawing like that

`<div id="canvas" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:300px;" onclick="q()"></div>`

I need to handle the event when clicking on it and get the coordinates on the canvas where it was clicked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the page x and y coordinates, and then minus the `canvas` offset to get them relative to the `canvas`.

```
function q(event) {
    event = event || window.event;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
        y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

    alert(x + ' ' + y);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajCPT/).

You should consider attaching events unobtrusively, i.e. *not* using the `onclick` HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "unobtrusively" ?

Comment: @Ahmad It is explained in the answer. Use a combination of `attachEvent()` and `addEventListener()`, in your JavaScript code. Don't mix behaviour and data layer.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can just read the .pageX and .pageY attributes directly.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#Where_did_they_click_that_div.3F

Answer (score 2):

Since HTML5, just get the layerX and layerY attributes of the event itself.  Nice!

Comment: Sweet! This is a GREAT solution. Anybody know a downside?